# Input Checking(if the input contains only certain characters) C++

Tags: c++

So, I have this assignment which requires me to develop a program that is basically a calculator but there are some different features of this calculator to ordinary ones. My program asks the user for some arithmetic operation questions(just addition and subtraction). The part that I am currently having trouble coding is that I need to check the input. The input should only contain the following elements (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, +, -, =). I would go through the indices to check if there is any that is not on this list if I could use Python. And I am pretty new to C++ so please do not be too harsh on me :). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us what you have so far in your program?

Comment: Actually there is not much yet. I do not have any idea about how to do this in c++. :(

Comment: You have to show what you have tried.  Otherwise we can't help you because we don't know which part you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a char from the user and check it by ASCII code ([ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/)).If user enters more than one char, you can use char array and loop for this.
Something like this for a char:

```
char input;
cin>>input;
switch((int)input){
//case 45,46,...,57 are digits. 61 is '=' and etc.
    case 48 ... 57: case 61: case 45: case 43: cout<<"Correct"<<endl; break;
    default: cout<<"Error"<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, you earned my downvote. This solution is verbose, nonstandard, unreadable, non-portable, and uses C-style casts, which are generally discouraged in C++.